# How to change OpenCV IP address using sockets?

Tags: python, opencv, sockets, networking

I am trying to change the IP address of OpenCV so it can sample other cameras.   The socket server and client work.  I am sending an entire address over the socket.   I don't need anything close to real-time performance.  Would just like to change cameras without restarting OpenCV.  This is an entertainment project.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket
import time
HEADER = 64
PORT = 5000
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = "localhost"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)
def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
#    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))
    camAddress = client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
    return
#face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('camAddress')

while 1:
   # send("ACK")
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(send("ACK")) ## gets camera IP address from server
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would appreciate any ideas or comments as to how to achieve this.  Thank you!

Comment: Excuse me for being an idiot.  In def send(msg): function I merely added camAddress after return and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for being an idiot. In def send(msg): function I merely added camAddress after return and it started working.  I hope others who wish to control OpenCV via sockets will find this useful.